# I need help in building gui around my console encryption decryption app

Tags: c++, ibm-rad

I'm fresh in programming and I was wondering how to put this code into gui that would have 2 text boxes ,2 buttons decrypt and encrypt and one output box that would show the encrypted or decrypted message.
I never build gui before and I dont know how to start with it, I already downloaded RAD and watched a few tutorials but It didn't worked

````
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void text_insert_into_table(char(*table)[4][4], char* text)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                table[i][j][k] = text[counter];
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void user_input_encrypt(char* table)
{
    cout << "wpisz tekst" << endl;
    fgets(table, 64, stdin);
}

void user_input_decrypt(char text[])
{
    string line;
    cout << "wpisz tekst do dekrypcji:";
    getline(cin, line);
    int counter = 0;
    string ascii_code = "";
    for (char c : line) {
        if (c != ':') {
            ascii_code += c;
        }
        else {
            int ascii_val = stoi(ascii_code);
            text[counter] = (char)ascii_val;
            ascii_code = "";
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

void user_key_input(char* table)
{
    cout << "wpisz klucz" << endl;
    getchar();
    fgets(table, 18, stdin);
    table[strlen(table) - 1] = 0;
}

void put_linekey_into_table(char* input, char* key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            *(input + 4 + (4 * i) + j) = *key;
            *(input + 44 + (4 * i) + j) = *key;
            key++;
        }
    }
}

void merge_tables_into_string(char(*table)[4][4], char(*string))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                string[k + 4 * j + 4 * 4 * i] = table[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}

void asci(char(*table)[4][4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                cout << (int)table[i][j][k] << ":";
            }
        }
    }
}

void XOR_function(char(*tabKey)[4][4], char(*tabText)[4][4], char(*tabEncrypted)[4][4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                tabEncrypted[i][j][k] = ((((tabText[i][j][k])) ^ ((tabKey[i][j][k]))));
            }
        }
    }
}

void quarterround(char* y0, char* y1, char* y2, char* y3)
{
    char x0 = *y0 + *y3, x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0;

    *y1 = *y1 ^ ((x0) <<= 7);

    x1 = *y1 + *y0;
    *y2 = *y2 ^ ((x1) <<= 7);

    x2 = *y2 + *y1;
    *y3 = *y3 ^ ((x2) <<= 7);

    x3 = *y3 + *y2;
    *y0 = *y0 ^ ((x3) <<= 7);
}

void rowround(char* y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        quarterround(y + i, y + i + 4, y + i + 8, y + i + 12);
        quarterround(y + i + 20, y + i + 24, y + i + 28, y + i + 16);
        quarterround(y + i + 40, y + i + 44, y + i + 32, y + i + 36);
        quarterround(y + i + 60, y + i + 48, y + i + 52, y + i + 56);
    }
}

void columnround(char* x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        quarterround(x + i, x + i + 16, x + i + 32, x + i + 48);
        quarterround(x + i + 20, x + i + 36, x + i + 52, x + i + 4);
        quarterround(x + i + 40, x + i + 56, x + i + 8, x + i + 24);
        quarterround(x + i + 60, x + i + 12, x + i + 28, x + i + 44);
    }
}

void doubleround(char* x)
{
    columnround(x);
    rowround(x);
}

char littleendian(char input, int j)
{
    return (input <<= j);
}

void hash_salsa(char* wsk_imput)
{
    char* wsk_output = wsk_imput;
    char words[16][4], coppy_words[16][4];
    int licznik = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            words[i][j] = *wsk_imput;
            coppy_words[i][j] = *wsk_imput;
            wsk_imput++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            words[i][j] = littleendian(coppy_words[i][j], j);
        }
    }

    char* wsk_words = &words[0][0];
    doubleround(wsk_words);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            words[i][j] = littleendian((words[i][j] + coppy_words[i][j]) % (int)pow(2, 32), j);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            *wsk_output = words[i][j] + 32;
            wsk_output++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string user_command;
    do
    {
        cout << "give command" << endl;
        cin >> user_command;
    } while (user_command != "encrypt" && user_command != "decrypt");

    char lineKey[18] = {};
    user_key_input(lineKey);

    char tabKey[4][4][4] = { { {'e', 'x', 'p', 'a'}, {66, 66, 66, 66}, {66, 66, 66, 66}, {66, 66, 66, 66}},
                           { {66, 66, 66, 66}, {'n', 'd', ' ', '3'}, {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}, {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}},
                           { {66, 66, 66, 66}, {66, 66, 66, 66}, {'2', '-', 'b', 'y'}, {66, 66, 66, 66}},
                           { {66, 66, 66, 66}, {66, 66, 66, 66}, {66, 66, 66, 66}, {'t', 'e', ' ', 'k'}} };

    put_linekey_into_table(tabKey[0][0], lineKey);
    hash_salsa(tabKey[0][0]);

    char text[512] = {};

    if (user_command == "encrypt") \
    {
        user_input_encrypt(text);
    }
    else
    {
        user_input_decrypt(text);
    }

    char tabText[4][4][4] = {};
    text_insert_into_table(tabText, text);

    char tabEncrypted[4][4][4] = {};
    XOR_function(tabKey, tabText, tabEncrypted);

    char tabOutput[65] = {};
    merge_tables_into_string(tabEncrypted, tabOutput);

    if (user_command == "encrypt")
    {
        cout << endl << endl << "ZAKODOWANE ASCII:  ";
        asci(tabEncrypted);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "OUTPUT: " << tabOutput;
    }
}```
````

Comment: If you want to create a "beautiful" UI using `HTML/CSS/JS`, you can use WebUI. This is an example of a console app becoming a very friendly GUI. https://github.com/alifcommunity/webui/blob/main/examples/C/minimal/main.c

Answer (score 1):

**There are several ways to include C++ console code in a GUI application, depending on the framework you're using. Here are a few examples:**

**Windows Forms:** If you're using Visual Studio on Windows, you can use the built-in Windows Forms Designer to create a GUI for your application, and then use the Form's event handlers to call your console code.

**Qt:** The Qt framework provides a cross-platform C++ framework for developing GUI applications. You can use the framework's classes to create the GUI, and then connect the GUI elements to your console code using slots and signals.

**MFC:** If you're using Visual Studio and prefer to use Microsoft's MFC framework to create a GUI, you can use the MFC classes to create the GUI, and then use the message map to handle events and call your console code.

**wxWidgets**: An open-source cross-platform GUI framework which allows to you design your UI with variety of widgets, and you can call your console code using event handlers.

It is also possible to create a GUI by using third-party libraries or frameworks such as wxWidgets, GTK+, and FLTK, which can be integrated with C++ code and can provide platform independent interfaces for user.

Please note the above is just a very basic overview and there are many nuances and details that you would need to learn about for each of the above libraries or frameworks to put your console code in to a GUI.

Comment: In my opinion, `MFC` is old and outdated, it should not be on the list.

Answer (score 1):

There are many GUI libraries, [MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-desktop-applications?view=msvc-170) is old and outdated, but [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/?view=netdesktop-6.0) is the next one, [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) and [WX](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) are old but still an option, [WebUI](https://github.com/alifcommunity/webui) and [WebView](https://github.com/webview/webview) are modern and have better nice looking UI, but only work if you know `HTML/CSS/JS`.